# Is there a compact contractible manifold?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds

Does there exist a compact connected manifold (without boundary), that has a trivial homotopy type?

Comment: the body of the question doesn't match the title

Comment: @Dominik First you wrote simply connected and then changed the title and your question to involve contractability.

Comment: The sphere $S^n$ for $n \ge 2$ is compact and has trivial fundamental group but is *not* contractible.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Now the question is right.

Comment: @SammyBlack Well the OP asked for a simply connected manifold at first.

Comment: The question should be self contained in the question body.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No. Closed manifold of dimension $n$ has $H^n(M;\mathbb Z/2)\cong\mathbb Z/2$.

Comment: Could you provide a proof or a reference?

Comment: @Dominik see e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_duality) or section 3.3 of [Hatcher's book](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html)

Comment: specifically page 236 on this link http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATch3.pdf

Comment: What you want to look for is Poincare Duality.